# Sending Image by file in Android (with FileInputStream) to PHP and saving mysql by Blob

Tags: php, android, mysql, blob

```
I'm trying to send an image converted by file and fileinputstream with my android app for my PHP server and then save it in BLOB field in MySQL DB, but I tried too many things, but nothing is ok. What can I do? And so, is this possible? Help, please!
```

My PHP server receives the json and saves other fields in like normal, but the image doesn't save in blob field as I do with java NetBeans.

```
public void cadastrarTAG(ModeloTAG tag) throws JSONException {

    FileWriter writeFile = null;

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("tag", String.valueOf(tag.getTag()));
    json.put("equipamento", String.valueOf(tag.getEquipamento()));
    json.put("data_registro", String.valueOf(tag.getData_registro()));
    json.put("login", String.valueOf(tag.getLogin()));
    json.put("descricao", String.valueOf(tag.getDescricao()));
    json.put("obs", String.valueOf(tag.getObs()));
    json.put("total_manutencoes", 0);
    json.put("setor", String.valueOf(tag.getSetor()));
    json.put("imagemFileLength", tag.getFile().length()); Field file length
    json.put("imagemFIS", tag.getFis()); field fileinputstream


    try {
        writeFile = new FileWriter(new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saida.json"));
        writeFile.write((json.toString()));
        writeFile.flush();
        writeFile.close();

    } catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("ERRO-> "+e);
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        log.geraLog("Cadastro de TAG ("+tag.getSetor()+") (MOBILE)", "PINS", (String) Login.rotinas[1], md.getDataHora());
        enviaJson.enviaJsonGravar(arquivoPHP, json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My PHP server receives the json and saves other fields in like normal, but the image doesn't save in blob field as I do with java NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function salvaImagem($conn, $json, $cod) {
          $flag['code'] = 0;
            echo "imagemFileLength 3 ---->>>>> ".$json->{'imagemFileLength'};
            echo "imagemFIS 3 ---->>>>> ".$json->{'imagemFIS'};

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("update tag set imagem = ? where id = ".$cod." and login = '{$json->{'login'}}'");
            $imageContent = fread($json->{'imagemFIS'}, filesize($json->{'imagemFileLength'}));
            //$imageContent = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $imageContent);
            //$stmt->bind_param('s',  mysql_real_escape_string($conn, $json->{'imagemFIS'}));
            $stmt->bind_param('s',  $imageContent);
            //$stmt->bindValue(1, $json->{'imagemFIS'});
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
              echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
              echo "Unable to create record";


            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to put the image in json by calling `json.put("imagemFIS", tag.getFis());`.

It just writes the `FileInputStream` object to json.
You should probably try and read image to `byte[]`, convert it to a Base64-encoded `String` and then put it in your json.

Also, it might be better to keep image file's path or URI as a `String` in your `ModeloTAG` object rather then `FileInputStream`, i.e.:

```
public void cadastrarTAG(ModeloTAG tag) throws JSONException {
    ...
    /* read bytes */
    try {
        final byte[] fileBytes = getFileBytes(new File(tag.getPath));
        json.put("image", Base64.encodeToString(fileBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // Handle the exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle the exception
    }
    ...
}

private byte[] getFileBytes(final String path) throw IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
    final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

    int read = 0;

    while ((read = fis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }

    fis.close();

    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

And on your backend you just need to decode the Base64-encoded string and save it as blob or just as is.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I already know how to save an image with JAVA front/backend. But my backend is PHP (in remote server and DB), so I´m trying to send my fileinputstream to PHP and use php to save in DB blob field

Comment: I understand that, but `FileInputStream` only contains the `FileDescriptor` which won't be of much use on your backend (apart from that you will have to somehow deserialize it), that's why you need to get an, i.e. Base64-encoded String from it.
On your backend you can use base64_decode to decode string to the array of bytes which you can save to the DB.

Comment: So your hint is send image converted into base64 to my php backend, convert the base64 to something like I can save into my db blob? is this?

Comment: @Kylukz yes, you're right. Or you can also try saving the image decoded from base64 to a file and keep it's path or id in the database.

Comment: I prefer to convert image base64 sent by my android app to my php server, coding this image and save like blob, because my desktop software already created like this; saving by blob

Comment: I have to use this? String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.NO_WRAP); or I have to use Base64 variable = byteArrayImage?

Comment: now I have a image in my php backend base64 and I can see it by calling my method on browser, so, I have to convert it into a byte array and use bind_param to save it like blob in mysql db?

Answer (score 0):

```
The problem is solved, I fix by sending imageview converted in Base64 for my PHP server and converting it into blob with this method.

public function salvaImagem($conn, $json, $cod) {
          $flag['code'] = 0;
            $blobData = base64_decode($json->{'imagem64'}); /* BASE64_DECODE and saving it like String with bind_param */
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("update tag set imagem = ? where id = ".$cod." and login = '{$json->{'login'}}'");
            $stmt->bind_param('s',  $blobData);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
              echo "New record created successfully";
            } else {
              echo "Unable to create record";


            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }
```